# Use Spring property @Value inside my custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

Guys I have a custom annotation which is designed to Mock the user in Spring boot integration tests which are secured with Spring security.

```
/**
 * Mock user for MVC authentication tests
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockMyAppUserSecurityContextFactory.class, setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_METHOD)
public @interface WithMockMyAppUser {

    long tokenExpMillis() default 36000L ;

    String[] roles() default {"NONE"};
}
```

And here is the usage of that:

```
@WithMockMyAppUser(roles={"ADMIN"})
class AddressServiceTest {
...
}
```

My question is, is that possible to somehow provide the roles using Spring property `@Value` instead of just having hardcoded `"ADMIN"` string here `@WithMockMyAppUser(roles={"ADMIN"})` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to extend `@WithMockMyAppUser`

```
public @interface WithMockCustomUser {
    ...
    String rolesProprety() default "";
```

Then you could use it in tests like following:

```
@WithMockMyAppUser(rolesProprety = "${test.roles}")
```

In order to make this work you would have to autowire a `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` bean into your `WithMockMyAppUserSecurityContextFactory` and utilize its `resolveEmbeddedValue` method:

```
public class WithMockMyAppUserSecurityContextFactory
        implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithMockMyAppUser> {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory;

    ...

    String[] getRoles(WithMockMyAppUser user){
        if (user.roles().length > 0) {
            return user.roles();
        }
        if (user.rolesProprety() != null) {
            String roleStr = factory.resolveEmbeddedValue(user.rolesProprety());
            if (roleStr != null && roleStr.length() > 0)
            return roleStr.split(",");
        }
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

First, check if the roles were provided hardcoded and return them in that case, otherwise try to resolve the `rolesProperty`.